# Is Definable Partition Principle not equivalent to AC over ZF?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, partitions

**Definable Partition Principle:** If $\phi;\psi$ are formulas in which only the symbol $x$ occur free, then: $$A = \{x \mid \phi\} \land B=\{x \mid \psi\} \land B \, ||| \, A \to B \leq A$$ where $|||$ means “is a partition of“; $B \leq A$ means there exists an injection from $B$ to $A$

> Is this provable in ZF?  If not, being a weaker principle than the full Partition Principle, would it be provable for it to be not equivalent to AC over ZF?

Comment: It is definitely not provable in ZF, since it is consistent $\mathbb R/\mathbb Q$ doesn't embed into $\mathbb R$. On the other hand, it follows from full partition principle, which is not known to imply AC, so I suspect the same holds for your principle.

Comment: We don't know if the full PP implies choice. How would a weaker condition do it?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, is it known to be NOT equivalent to the axiom of choice? I've edited the question.

Comment: If it's not known to imply AC, how would it be known to not imply it?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, the full PP is the one not known to imply AC! This principle is a much weaker form, so it might be the case that this weaker version can be easily provable to be not equivalent to AC